# excel file to json conversion

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert an excel file with two columns into a Json file. However, I want to keep the hierarchy as well some how. For example from the excel file below, I want the json to form a hierarchy in  such a way that  "Charles Johnson" is the root value, and the size associated to him is 5395. Similarly, in the second row, "Donald Williams" works under "Charles Johnson" and the size for him is 3057. And so on, the last name in each row of the file connects it to its parent nodes. And i want to use the .split(-) function I have been stuck at this for quite a while till i finally gave up:/ Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
Charles Johnson 4184
Charles Johnson-Donald Williams 8385
Charles Johnson-Donald Williams-Daniel Fertig   428
Charles Johnson-Donald Williams-Daniel Fertig-Lino Walling  1091
Charles Johnson-Donald Williams-Daniel Fertig-Lino Walling-Jim Cooke    318
```

Desired Output Type:

```
{
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [{
        "name": "analytics",
        "children": [{
            "name": "cluster",
            "children": [{
                "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
                "size": 3938
            }, {
                "name": "CommunityStructure",
                "size": 3812
            }, {
                "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
                "size": 6714
            }, {
                "name": "MergeEdge",
                "size": 743
            }]
        }
    }]]
}
```

Comment: fix indentation of your example

Comment: you mentioned that your excel file has two columns, what I can see is one line, where are the columns?

Comment: Is there any way I can attach an excel file here, the numeric part is the second column but its coming out as one when I simply copy paste from excel

Comment: Oh ok fixed it. Indentation fixed it as you said..

Comment: @ gawi, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use recursion when parsing every single row. Assuming that you always have two tab separated columns and there is only one root your code could look like that:

```
//example data
var str = "Charles Johnson\t4184\nCharles Johnson-Donald Williams\t8385\nCharles Johnson-Donald Williams-Daniel Fertig\t428\nCharles Johnson-Donald Williams-Daniel Fertig-Lino Walling\t1091\nCharles Johnson-Donald Williams-Daniel Fertig-Lino Walling-Jim Cooke\t318";
var lines = str.split("\n");

var name_ = lines[0].split("\t")[0];
var val_ = lines[0].split("\t")[1];
var obj = {name:     name_,
           children: [],
           value:    val_};
//process all lines
for (var i=1;i<lines.length;i++) {
  var addr = lines[i].split("\t")[0].split("-");
  var val = lines[i].split("\t")[1];
  var local_obj  = obj;
  var recursive_obj;
  for (var j=1;j<addr.length;j++) {
    recursive_obj = null;
    for (var k=0;k<local_obj.children.length;k++) {
      if (local_obj.children[k].name==addr[j]) {
        recursive_obj=local_obj.children[k];
      }
    }
    if (recursive_obj==null) {
      recursive_obj = {name:     addr[j],
                       children: [],
                       value:    null
                      };
      local_obj.children.push(recursive_obj);
    }   
    local_obj=recursive_obj;
  }
  recursive_obj.value=val;
}

//print a json result
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: @ gawi..Thank you so very much bro...I think I can make this work with your code...Appreciate your prompt response and help :)

Comment: @ Gawi, I just checked on jsonlist.com that the output is not in a valid json format:/...it gives an error for the last value of size

Comment: @Khan JSON.stringify is the standard JSON converter for javascript, so you should get correct json string, what is the exact error?

Comment: @ Gawi...Apologies for the late reply..I think I edited out the string a little so it gave an error, However I am trying to achieve a desired output as mentioned above..It's a format like flare.json. Can you please let me know if i can somehow convert it into a flare.json format somehow, as I would be using this json file in D3 visualizations..

Comment: If you think the input file needs to be modified to achieve a flare.json format then I'll be ok with that too, but I am not sure at the moment how to...Thank you so much for all you assistance:)

Comment: @ Gawi...Thank you so much for your solution, your suggestion worked like a charm :)..Appreciate the help, thank you so much again :)